# How to fill fields according to iteration values of a foreach in JSF?

Tags: jsf, foreach, jstl, el

How can I fill my fields in a class according to a variable in a foreach loop?

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="#{resource.numberOfSkills}">
                                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
               *Here my problem* ---> <h:selectOneMenu value="#{**skills.skillFromSelectList${i}**}">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Comp" itemValue="" />
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{skills.listOfTitlesOfSkills}"/>
                                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                                    <p:rating value="#{skills.levelSkill}"/> 
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </c:forEach>
```

In my Skills class (different from the Skill class): i have fields:

```
private Skill skillFromSelectList1;
private Skill skillFromSelectList2;
private Skill skillFromSelectList3;
private Skill skillFromSelectList4;
private Skill skillFromSelectList5;
private Skill skillFromSelectList6;
```

I want to fill each of these fields with {**skills.skillFromSelectList${i}**}">. So for the first loop the selected item will be put in skillFromSelectList1. For the second loop the selected items will be put in skillFromSelectList2, etc.

Comment: You could put the `Skill`s in an Array and then access them with `skills.skillArray[{i}]`. This array-like accessor is pretty useful for such cases, IMHO.

Comment: I have an error, it doesn't works, Error parsing #{skills.skillArray[{i}]}. I don't want to take values from an array but fill this array with values of my selected menu. Thx for your reply.

Comment: BalusC - of course - just gave that same idea in an actual answer. Please try his code out.

Comment: I tried his second code (with the list) but i have to initialize the list before (with "1","2","3", etc). Can i fill an empty list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting EL expressions like so `#{...#{...}...}` is in any case invalid. You should see an EL expression as a single big evaluation context where various variables can interact with each other.

Your concrete problem can be solved by creating another EL variable which represents the desired property name and then evaluating it as a dynamic property of the bean using the brace notation `#{bean[property]}`.

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="#{resource.numberOfSkills}">
    <c:set var="propertyName" value="skillFromSelectList#{i}" />
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{skills[propertyName]}">
        ...
```

**However**, there's a design problem. You keep repeating `Skill` propreties. Why not just getting hold of them in a single `Skill[]` or `List<Skill>` property? Then you can just do

```
<c:forEach items="#{skills.skillFromSelectList}" varStatus="loop">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{skills.skillFromSelectList[loop.index]}">
        ...
```

Comment: It fills the skillFromSelectList list indeed but i have to put values in the list before... Strange? (for your second code)

Comment: I mean, can i fill an empty list?

Comment: If the size is fixed, use an array. If the size is dynamic, use a list. In your case it's apparently fixed (by an application wide configuration setting), so stick to array.